# Why need to pass jQuery object as parameter to closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To avoid global variables in JavaScript code I many times seen that people use this construct:

```
(function($) {
    // here code
    // here code
})(jQuery);
```

So I have questions: why we need to declare function argument as `$` and why we need to pass `jQuery` object as argument?

Comment: What happens if you're using `$` in other pieces of code to mean something that isn't _jQuery_?

Comment: What does this have to do with [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)? Do you mean "a closure"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. You can name the function argument whatever you want it to be. It is just a common/best practice of people using jQuery since it is common to use $ as an alias to jQuery library object.

The reason why you should do it is because there are other libraries that use $ as an alias to their library objects. It is needed to avoid collisions with those libraries since function closure will ensure $ to be jQuery object inside the wrapper function.

Here's an example:

```
(function (myJqueryAlias) {
     console.log(myJqueryAlias('document') === jQuery('document'));
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I know all about $. you should read my updated answer

Comment: Your `===` test will never pass - jQuery will create a brand new object for `$('document')` every time you invoke it that'll have a different reference each time.

Comment: It does not really matter that $ is already defined by jQuery unless you are 100% sure that $ will never be overwritten by other libraries or by your code.

Comment: @Juno  can I access to jQuery's `$` object within this closure? If I can it's mean that sens of passing jQuery object as parameter is _only avoiding collisions_ when accessing to `$`?

Comment: If you want to use $, you just have to name your parameter as $.

Answer (score 0):

With this you archive that in this block you still have $ as jQuery and you can still write stuff like "$("selector")" instead of "jQuery("selector")".
And outside this block the variable $ is still what it should be (for example you use another JSLib that uses the $ too)

Comment: i.e. within closure I didn't have access to `$` variable? Or the only reason to explicitly pass `jQuery`  as `$` is to avoid collisions?

Comment: @MyTitle yes when outside of this function jQuery.noConflict() is called then u dont have access to $. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ for more informations